# Cant Install snap on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, snap

no matter how i do it, weather it be using yay or installing it manually i always run into this:

```
[rezzor@GoldExperience snapd]$ makepkg -si  
==> Making package: snapd 2.48.2-1 (Sat Dec 26 22:24:11 2020)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found snapd-2.48.2.tar.xz
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    snapd-2.48.2.tar.xz ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting snapd-2.48.2.tar.xz with bsdtar
bsdtar: Failed to set default locale
==> Starting prepare()...
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
*** Setting version to '2.48.2-1' from user.
# github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-update-ns
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-956069493/000017.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrouplist':
getgrouplist_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x20): warning: Using 'getgrouplist' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-956069493/000016.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrgid_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x34): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-956069493/000016.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrnam_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x75): warning: Using 'getgrnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-956069493/000016.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetpwnam_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0xb5): warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-956069493/000016.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetpwuid_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0xf4): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-956069493/000023.o: in function `_cgo_26061493d47f_C2func_getaddrinfo':
cgo_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x34): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
# github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-exec
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-345583192/000002.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrouplist':
getgrouplist_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x20): warning: Using 'getgrouplist' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-345583192/000001.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrgid_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x34): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-345583192/000001.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrnam_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x75): warning: Using 'getgrnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-345583192/000001.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetpwnam_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0xb5): warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-345583192/000001.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetpwuid_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0xf4): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-345583192/000020.o: in function `_cgo_26061493d47f_C2func_getaddrinfo':
cgo_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x34): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
# github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snapctl
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-040420955/000019.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrouplist':
getgrouplist_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x20): warning: Using 'getgrouplist' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-040420955/000018.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrgid_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x34): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-040420955/000018.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetgrnam_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x75): warning: Using 'getgrnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-040420955/000018.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetpwnam_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0xb5): warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-040420955/000018.o: in function `_cgo_bbce630bddcc_Cfunc_mygetpwuid_r':
cgo_lookup_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0xf4): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-040420955/000004.o: in function `_cgo_26061493d47f_C2func_getaddrinfo':
cgo_unix.cgo2.c:(.text+0x34): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
make: Entering directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data'
make -C systemd all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/systemd'
if command -v shellcheck >/dev/null; then shellcheck snapd.run-from-snap snapd.core-fixup.sh; fi
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/systemd'
make -C systemd-user all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/systemd-user'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/systemd-user'
make -C systemd-env all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/systemd-env'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/systemd-env'
make -C dbus all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/dbus'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/dbus'
make -C env all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/env'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/env'
make -C desktop all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/desktop'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data/desktop'
make: Leaving directory '/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/src/snapd-2.48.2/data'
/home/rezzor/snapd/snapd/PKGBUILD: line 92: autoreconf: command not found
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> autoreconf: command not found

`autoreconf` is a part from [`base-devel`](https://archlinux.org/groups/any/base-devel/) you can install it through :

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel
```

[Installing snap on Arch Linux](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-arch-linux)